# Explain difference between SQL Server real datatype and Excel representation

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

The real datatype in SQL Server is precision 7 yet sometimes Excel shows more precision than this, and sometimes completely different decimal parts. Can someone please explain these results:

```
**Number Inserted | Displayed in SSMS | Displayed in Excel**
_________________________________________________________
12345678             1.234568E+07        12345678
1234567.1            1234567             1234567.125
1234567.5            1234568             1234567.5
1234567.45           1234568             1234567.5
1234567.59           1234568             1234567.625
1234567.69           1234568             1234567.75
1.12345678           1.123457            1.123456836
1.5123456            1.512346            1.512345552
90000000             9E+07               90000000
99999999             1E+08               100000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, the SSMS display is formatted to 7 significant figures, with exponential notation for numbers greater than 10,000,000.

The Excel display is probably displaying double precision, and for these purposes (nearly) the  actual binary values stored by the "precision 7" numbers.

Comment: Why doesn't SQL Server simply reject values having > 7 significant digits?  This would be much better than having applications displaying patently wrong numbers (1234567.59 != 1234567.625)

Comment: You need to read [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and other similar floating point references, and use a fixed point type if that is your need.